# How can I solve first order matrix differential equation?

Tags: differential-equations, matrix

$dX/dt= AX(t)-iG$,
where `X={{x1},{x2}}`, `A={{a1,b}, {b,a2}}` and `G={{G1},{G2}}`. `G` can be considered as time depended and time independent also.

Comment: [`DSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve.html) or [`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve.html)?

Comment: DSolve. Thanks...

Answer (score 4):

Actually the OP's symbolic matrix works, too:

```
DSolve[D[{x1[t], x2[t]}, t] == {{a1, b}, {b, a2}}.{x1[t], x2[t]} - I*{g1[t], g2[t]},
 {x1, x2}, t]
```

> [Long output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xyzrp.png)

---

Original answer:

Here's a way. You have to have an explicit matrix `a`, since the solution depends on the structure of its invariant eigenspaces.

```
SeedRandom[1];    (* for reproducibility *)
Block[{a, g, x},
 a = RandomInteger[{-2, 2}, {2, 2}];
 g = {g1[t], g2[t]};
 x = {x1[#], x2[#]} &;
 gensol = DSolve[x'[t] == a.x[t] - I*g, x[t], t]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

With `g1`, `g2` constant:

```
Block[{g1 = 1 &, g2 = -1 &}, gensol] // Simplify
(*
  {{x1[t] -> I/2 - 1/2 I E^(-2 + 2 t) + E^(2 t) C[1], 
    x2[t] -> 1/4 (4 I - 3 I E^(2 - 2 t) - I E^(-2 + 2 t) + 2 E^(2 t) C[1] - 
        2 E^(-2 t) (C[1] - 2 C[2]))}}
*)
```

With functions for `g1`, `g2`:

```
sol1 = Block[{g1 = Sin[#] &, g2 = Cos[#] &}, gensol] // Simplify
(*
  {{x1[t] -> E^(2 t) C[1] - 1/5 I E^(-2 + 2 t) (Cos[1] + 2 Sin[1]) + 
      1/5 I (Cos[t] + 2 Sin[t]), 
    x2[t] -> 1/10 (-4 I Cos[t] + E^(-2 t) (5 (-1 + E^(4 t)) C[1] + 
           10 C[2] + 5 I E^2 Cos[1] - I E^(-2 + 4 t) (Cos[1] + 2 Sin[1])) + 2 I Sin[t])}}
*)
```

Check the solution with that obtained by calling `DSolve` with `g1` and `g2` defined to be `Sin` and `Cos`.

```
SeedRandom[1];
Block[{a, g, x, g1 = Sin[#] &, g2 = Cos[#] &},
 a = RandomInteger[{-2, 2}, {2, 2}];
 g = {g1[t], g2[t]};
 x = {x1[#], x2[#]} &;
 sol2 = DSolve[x'[t] == a.x[t] - I*g, x[t], t]
 ]
(*
  {{x1[t] -> E^(2 t) C[1] + 1/5 I (Cos[t] + 2 Sin[t]), 
    x2[t] -> 1/2 E^(-2 t) (-1 + E^(4 t)) C[1] + E^(-2 t) C[2] - 
      1/10 I E^(-4 t) ((-1 + 5 E^(4 t)) Cos[t] - 2 Sin[t]) + 
      1/10 I E^(-4 t) (-1 + E^(4 t)) (Cos[t] + 2 Sin[t])}}
*)
```

It's difficult to see the equivalence since the constants of integration in `sol1` and `sol2` are independent.  We can solve for one set in terms of the other by changing `C[1]`, `C[2]` to `C[3]`, `C[4]` respectively in `sol2`.

```
Solve[({x1[t], x2[t]} /. First@sol1) ==
  ({x1[t], x2[t]} /. First@sol2 /. {C[1] -> C[3], C[2] -> C[4]}),
 {C[1], C[2]}]
(*
  {{C[1] -> -((-5 E^2 C[3] - I Cos[1] - 2 I Sin[1])/(5 E^2)), 
    C[2] -> -((-10 E^2 C[4] - I Cos[1] + 5 I E^4 Cos[1] - 2 I Sin[1])/(10 E^2))}}
*)
```

This shows one solution may be transformed into the other.

Comment: Thanks sir. But it seems to be complicated result.

Comment: @Anilchauhan Yes, it does.  But what did you expect from a problem that depends on three real parameters and two functional parameters? (I assume it's using variation of parameters.)

Comment: Dear Michael, I found that if G is time independent, solution is much easier than the opposite case. only two constant will appear in the solution for G.  But for G to be time dependenct, solution becomes too complicated. I think it requires initial conditions to make it simple. Thanks for your kind support. tc

Comment: Dear Michael, I am getting integral sign varying from 1 to t instead of "Integrate" as you have shown in the link "Long output here". What does it mean by integral varying from 1 to t. Can you please comment on this? I didn't put any limit over there. A = {{a1, b}, {b, a2}};
Eigenvalues[A]
X[t_] = {x[t], y[t]};
G[t_] = {g1[t], 
   g2[t]};
system = MapThread[#1 == #2 &, {X'[t], A.X[t] - \[Iota] G[t]}];
sol = DSolve[system, {x, y}, t]